# A question on Limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Let us consider
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{3+i a-i/2}{3+i a+i/2}\right)^{2x}
\end{equation}
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Depending on the sign of $a$, the limit is either 0 (for $a>0$) or infinity (for $a<0$) which one can obtain by writing the expression $\left(\frac{3+i a-i/2}{3+i a+i/2}\right)^{2x}=e^{2x\ln\left(\frac{3+ia-i/2}{3+ia+i/2} \right)}$ and looking at the sign of the real part of the exponent.

Now, I would like to look at the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sinh(3+i a-i/2)}{\sinh(3+i a+i/2)}\right)^{2x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{2x\ln\left(\frac{\sinh(3+i a-i/2)}{\sinh(3+i a+i/2)}\right)}
\end{equation}
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Here, looks like the sign of the exponent does not depend just on the sign of $a$.

Since, $\sinh$ is a monotonic function, I was expecting the result to be the same as previous case.

How do I go about finding all the values of $a$ for which the limit vanishes and all the values of $a$ for which the limit is infinite?

Comment: Logarithms and powers of complex numbers are not even uniquely defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity
$
  \sinh(z) = \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}
$
to get
\begin{align}
f(a)&:=\frac{\sinh(3+i a-i/2)}{\sinh(3+i a+i/2)}\\
&= \frac{e^{3+i a-i/2} - e^{-3-i a+i/2}} 
{e^{3+i a+i/2} - e^{-3-i a-i/2}}\\
&= \frac{e^{6+2i a} - e^{i}} 
{e^{6+2i a+i} - 1} \\
&= \frac{e^{6+2i a} - e^{i}} 
{e^{6+2i a+i} - 1} 
\cdot \frac{e^{6-2i a-i} - 1}{e^{6-2i a-i} - 1}
\\
&= \frac{e^{12-i} - e^{6+2ia} - e^{6i+2a+1} + e^i} 
{e^{12}+1 - e^{6+2i a+i} - e^{6-2i a-i}} \\ 
&= \frac{e^{12}[cos(1)-i\sin(1)] - e^{6+2ia} - e^{6i+2a+1} + e^i} 
{e^{12}+1 - 2e^{6} \cos(2a+1)}.\tag{*}\label{*}
\end{align}
Since $e^{12}$ is dominates the other terms, the denominator in the obtained expression is positive, and the nominator has positive real part $e^{12}\cos(1)>0.5 e^{12} > e^6$.

Next, we use the fact the basic fact about complex numbers that for $u \in \mathbb C$
$$
  \lim_{x\to \infty} u^{2x}
$$
converges if $|u|<1$ or if $u=\pm 1$, and diverges otherwise. It only remains to estimate the absolute value of the nominator and denominator of the formula \eqref{*}. We have
$$
\big|e^{12}[cos(1)-i\sin(1)] - e^{6+2ia} - e^{6i+2a+1} + e^i \big|
< e^{12} \cos(1) + 3 e^6,
$$
and
$$
\big| e^{12}+1 - 2e^{6} \cos(2a+1) \big| 
> e^{12} - 3 e^6.
$$
However, as $\cos(1) \approx 0.54$ and $e^{12}/e^{6} = e^6 \approx 403$,
$$
  e^{12} \cos(1) + 3 e^6 < e^{12} - 3 e^6.
$$
We conclude that
$$
|f(a)| =  \left| \frac{\sinh(3+i a-i/2)}{\sinh(3+i a+i/2)} \right|
< 1,
$$
and so the sequence $(f(a))^{2x}$ **converges** to 0 as $x\to \infty$ for any $a\in \mathbb R$.

**Back to the first problem:** We want to know if $(g(a))^{2x}$ converges as $x\to\infty$, where
$$
g(a) = \frac{3+i a-i/2}{3+i a+i/2}.
$$
We have
$$
  |3+i a \pm i/2|^2 = 9 + (a\pm 1/2)^2 = 9 + a^2 + \tfrac 1 4 \pm a, 
$$
and so $|g(a)|<1$ if and only if $a>0$. (If $a=0$ $|g(a)|=1$, but it is not equal $\pm 1$.) We conclude that $(g(a))^{2x}$ converges (to $0$) if and only if $a>0$.